# How to insert various records from multiple tables with a condition

Tags: insert, sqlite, relational-theory

I am creating a relational database and I have 2 tables currently ( `Staff` and `Student`)

**Staff Looks Like this**

| StaffID | Class | TotalPhonesConfiscated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | S201 | 1 |
| 2 | S202 | 0 |
| 3 | S203 | 1 |

**Student Looks like this**

| StudentID | Phone_Model |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | iPhone7 |
| 2 | Samsung |

I have created another table called `Phones`

I am trying to insert these specific records from both tables: `StudentID` and `StaffID`, `Class`, and `Phone_Models`, into the new table `Phones`. However it should only insert the records from the `Staff` table based on the condition if the staff's `TotalPhonesConfiscated` is >= 1.

I have attempted but this does not provide the correct table:

```
INSERT INTO Phones ( StudentID, 
                     StaffID, 
                     Phone_Model, 
                     Class
                   )
SELECT   StudentID, 
         StaffID, 
         Phone_Model, 
         Class
FROM Student, Staff
WHERE TotalPhonesConfiscated >= 1;
```

I can't figure out how to insert the records so it looks like each individual `StaffID` matches with each individual `StudentID`, it seems to work for the `Student` records but not for the `Staff` records.
In theory what I want should look like this:

| StudentID | StaffID | Phone_Model | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | iPhone7 | S201 |
| 2 | 3 | iPhone11 | S203 |

Is there something missing from my SQL statement?

Comment: Please tag your post with the RDBMS you're using. As for you problem, you'll need a join condition. https://www.sqlshack.com/a-step-by-step-walkthrough-of-sql-inner-join/ Note, this is link is for SQL Server, since I do not know what RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In theory what I want should look like this:
>
> ```
> | StudentID | StaffID | Phone_Model | Class |
> | --------- | ------- |------------ | ----- |
> |  1        | 1       | iPhone7     | S201
> |  2        | 3       | iPhone11    | S203
> ```
>
> Is there something missing from my SQL statement?

You are missing  relation between `Staff` and `Student`. You need a column `StaffID int` in the `Student` table.

```
create table  Staff  (
StaffID int ,
Class varchar(10),
TotalPhonesConfiscated int );

insert into Staff values 
(1,'S201',1),
(2,'S202',0),
(3,'S203',1);


create table  Student  (
StudentID int ,
Phone_Model varchar(20),
StaffID int );

insert into Student values 
(1,'iPhone7',1),
(2,'Samsung',3);


create table  Phones  (
StudentID int,
StaffID int ,
Phone_Model varchar(20),
Class varchar(10));
```

Then you can insert the data:

```
INSERT INTO Phones ( StudentID, 
                     StaffID, 
                     Phone_Model, 
                     Class
                   )
SELECT   StudentID, 
         Student.StaffID, 
         Phone_Model, 
         Class
FROM Student 
INNER JOIN  Staff on Student.StaffID=Staff.StaffID
WHERE TotalPhonesConfiscated >= 1;


select * from Phones;
```

Would result on:

> Result:
>
> ```
> StudentID StaffID Phone_Model   Class
> 1           1       iPhone7     S201
> 2           3       Samsung     S203
> ```

Comment: Thanks it works, I did think of this just didn't want to add a new column to the student table because I am handling much larger datasets and tables compared to the ones I gave in the question. 